# c++ - Solution to 2-sum using unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map

Okay so I am trying to solve the `2-SUM` problem in c++. Given a file of 1000000 numbers in arbitrary order, I need to determine if there exist pairs of integers whose sum is `t` where `t is each of [-10000, 10000]`. So this basically the `2-SUM` problem.

So, I coded up my solution in C++ wherein I used `unordered_map` as my hash table. I am ensuring low `load` on the hash table. But still this takes around `1hr 15mins` to finish(successful). Now, I am wondering if it should be that slow. Further reducing the load factor did not give any considerable performance boost.

I have no idea where I can optimise the code. I tried different load factors, doesn't help. This is question from a MOOC and people have been able to get this done in around 30 mins using the same hash table approach. Can anybody help me make this code faster. Or at least give a hint as to where the code might be slowing down.

Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./2sum <filename>" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream output("log.txt");
    std::unordered_map<long, int> data_map;
    data_map.max_load_factor(0.05);

    long tmp;
    while(input >> tmp){
        data_map[tmp] += 1;
    }

    std::cerr << "input done!" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "load factor " << data_map.load_factor() << std::endl;

    //debug print.
    for(auto iter = data_map.begin(); iter != data_map.end(); ++iter){
        output << iter->first << " " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cerr << "debug print done!" << std::endl;

    //solve
    long ans = 0;

    for(long i = -10000; i <= 10000; ++i){
        //try to find a pair whose sum = i.

        //debug print.
        if(i % 100 == 0)
            std::cerr << i << std::endl;

        for(auto iter = data_map.begin(); iter != data_map.end(); ++iter){
            long x = iter->first;
            long y = i - x;

            if(x == y)
                continue;

            auto search_y = data_map.find(y);
            if(search_y != data_map.end()){
                ++ans;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << ans << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, what is the range of the 1M numbers?

Comment: @thecoder no such range is specified. But they are large - of the order 10^11.

Comment: When you say: `t is each of [-10000, 10000]` do you mean "exactly +10000 or -10000" or "in the `[-10000, 10000]` range"? Which of the two, please.

Comment: `t` takes on all values in the range `[-10000, 10000]`

Comment: I think I've got it to the minimal time . Please check the code in my answer and let me know how it behaves on your data set.

Comment: @AneeshDandime As I saw you accepted my answer, I assumed you ran the code against the data provided in your input file. If I'm correct, would you mind to tell how long did it take to finish the job?

Comment: I did not yet run it on the original data set but only on smaller ones. It gave me the right answers with a faster run time. I haven't had the time to run the code on the full set(have exams). Will do soon and inform asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a uniform set with all sums equally probable, the below will finish in seconds. Otherwise, for any missing sums, on my laptop takes about 0.75 secs to check for a missing sum.

The solution has a minor improvement in comparison with the OP's code: checking for duplicates and eliminating them.

Then it opens through a Monte Carlo heuristic: for about 1% of the total numbers, randomly picks one from the set and searches for all the sums in the `[minSum, maxSum]` range that can be made having one term as the randomly picked number and the rest of them. This will pre-populate the `sums` set with... say... 'sum that can be found trivially'. In my tests, using 1M numbers generated randonly between -10M and 10M, this is the single step necessary and takes a couple of seconds.

For pathological numbers distributions, in which some of the sum values are missing (or have not been found through the random heuristic), the second part uses a targeted exhaustive search over the not-found `sum` values, very much on the same line as the solution in the OP.

---

Extra explanations for the `random/Monte Carlo heuristic`(to address @AneeshDandime's comment of):

> Though i do not fully understand it at the moment

Well, it's simple. Think like this: the naive approach is to take all the input values and add them in pairs, but retain only the sum in the [-10k, 10k]. It is however terrible expensive (O[N^2]). An immediate refinement would be: pick a value `v0`, then determine which other `v1` values stand a chance to give a sum in the [-10k, 10k] range. If the input values are sorted, it's easier: you only need to select `v1`-s in the `[-10k-v0, 10k-v0]`; a good improvement, but if you keep this as the only approach, an exhaustive search would still be O(log2(N)*N*[-10k, 10k]).

*However, this approach still has its value*: if the input values are uniformly distributed, it will quickly populate the `known sums` set with the most common values (and spend the rest of time trying to find infrequent or missing `sum` values).

To capitalize, instead of using this 'til the end, one can proceed with a limited number of steps, hope to populate the majority of the sums. After that, we can switch the focus and enter the 'targeted search for `sum` values', but only for the `sum` value not found at this step.

---

[Edited: prev bug corrected. Now the algo is stable in regards with values present multiple times or single occurrences in input]

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>


int main() {
  typedef long long value_type;

  // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  // substitute this with your input sequence from the file
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<value_type> initRnd(-5500, 10000000);

  std::vector<value_type> sorted_vals;


  for(ulong i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    int rnd=initRnd(gen);
    sorted_vals.push_back(rnd);
  }
  std::cout << "Initialization end" << std::endl;
  // end of input
  // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  // use some constants instead of magic values
  const value_type sumMin=-10000, sumMax=10000;

  // Mapping val->number of occurrences
  std::unordered_map<value_type, size_t> hashed_vals;

  for(auto val : sorted_vals) {
    hashed_vals[val]=hashed_vals[val]++;
  }

  // retain only the unique values and sort them
  sorted_vals.clear();
  for(auto val=hashed_vals.begin(); val!=hashed_vals.end(); ++val) {
    sorted_vals.push_back(val->first);
  }
  std::sort(sorted_vals.begin(), sorted_vals.end());


  // Store the encountered sums here
  std::unordered_set<int> sums;

  // some 1% iterations, looking at random for pair of numbers which will contribute with
  // sum in the [-10000, 10000] range, and we'll collect those sums.
  // We'll use the sorted vector of values for this purpose.
  // If we are lucky, most of the sums (if not all) will be already filled in
  std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> rndPick(0, sorted_vals.size());
  size_t numRandomPicks=size_t(sorted_vals.size()*0.1);
  if(numRandomPicks > 75000) {
    numRandomPicks=75000;
  }
  for(size_t i=0; i<numRandomPicks;i++) {
    // pick a value index at random
    size_t randomIx=rndPick(gen);
    value_type val=sorted_vals[randomIx];

    // now search for the values between -val-minSum and -val+maxSum;
    auto low=std::lower_bound(sorted_vals.begin(), sorted_vals.end(), sumMin-val);
    if(low==sorted_vals.end()) {
      continue;
    }
    auto high=std::upper_bound(sorted_vals.begin(), sorted_vals.end(), sumMax-val);
    if(high==sorted_vals.begin()) {
      continue;
    }
    for(auto rangeIt=low; rangeIt!=high; rangeIt++) {
      if(*rangeIt!=val || hashed_vals[val] > 1) {
        // if not the same as the randomly picked value
        // or if it is the same but that value occurred more than once in input
        auto sum=val+*rangeIt;
        sums.insert(sum);
      }
    }
    if(sums.size()==size_t(sumMax-sumMin+1)) {
      // lucky us, we found them all
      break;
    }
  }

  // after which, if some sums are not present, we'll search for them specifically
  if(sums.size()!=size_t(sumMax-sumMin+1)) {
    std::cout << "Number of sums still missing: "
              << size_t(sumMax-sumMin+1)-sums.size()
              << std::endl
    ;
    for(int sum=sumMin; sum<=sumMax; sum++) {
      if(sums.find(sum)==sums.end()) {
        std::cout << "looking for sum: " << sum ;
        // we couldn't find the sum, so we'll need to search for it.
        // We'll use the unique_vals hash map this time to search for the other value
        bool found=false;
        for(auto i=sorted_vals.begin(); !found && i!=sorted_vals.end(); ++i) {
          value_type v=*i;
          value_type other_val=sum-v;
          if(  // v---- either two unequal terms to be summed or...
               (other_val != v || hashed_vals[v] > 1) // .. the value occurred more than once
            && hashed_vals.find(other_val)!=hashed_vals.end() // and the other term exists
          ) {
            // found. Record it as such and break
            sums.insert(sum);
            found=true;
          }
        }
        std::cout << (found ? " found" : " not found") << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Total number of distinct sums found: " << sums.size() << std:: endl;
}
```

Comment: Uhh i just ran it and it is giving wrong answer. Let me restate the problem statement in case it's not clear. I need to find the number of target values `t` in the interval `[-10000, 10000]` such that there exist two distinct numbers `x,y` in the given data set that satisfy `x+y = t`. If you got it right then I do not understand the solution(plus it gives wrong answer).

Comment: The solution totals the number of pair for which the sum is in the `[-10000, +10000]`. Do you need the number of values in the `[-10000, +10000]` for which there exist at least one pair with the sum of the picked value?

Comment: @Adrain I need the number of values in [-10000, 10000] such that there exists a pair in the data set that sum to that value.

Comment: @AneeshDandime Just to make sure: for each value of `t` in [-10000, 10000], you don't need all the number of pairs that realizes a sum of `t`, but only if such a pair exists?

Comment: Yes I only need to find if such pairs exist. Number of pairs is not required.

Comment: I will try this code in a while. Though i do not fully understand it at the moment.

Comment: @AneeshDandime Corrected a bug and provided extra explanation - check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can reserve the space earlier for [unordered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) map. It should increase performance a bit

Comment: okay i think this would not produce and observable change in performance because the 1hr 15 min time that i mentioned did not include the input time. Gave it a run on a smaller input also, no substantial change.

Answer (score 0):

What about sorting the array first and then for each element in the array, use binary search to find the number which would make it closer to -10000 and keep going "right" until you reached a sum +10000

This way you will avoid going through the array 20000 times.

Comment: This would be a slower solution. The complexity of the solution you are proposing would be O(nlgn) whereas my solution works in average O(n) time - given the hash table in properly implemented and because I am using STL this should be true.

Comment: Doing a one time "pre computation" for an algorithm which will avoid the next 20 000 executions may be a good thing even if it has a worse complexity.

Try to calculate the time it would actually take to sort that array and compare it with your 1h execution.

You will then be able to decide if it is worth it or not.